# Integration over one point set

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose we have a continuous function $f:S^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ on the standard sphere. What value is given for the following integral $$\int_{\lbrace p\rbrace }f(x) \text{d$vol_{\lbrace p\rbrace}$(x)},$$

where $p\in S^2$ is any fixed point and d$vol_{\lbrace p\rbrace }$(x) is the "Riemannian volume element"? I am not sure what exactly the definition of the Riemannian volume element is in the above context, since the manifold consists of one point only.  Is it just $\int_{\lbrace p\rbrace }f(x) \text{dvol(x)}:=f(p)$?

Edit: The Riemannian volume element d$vol_{\lbrace p\rbrace }$(x) is most likely meant as the Riemannian volume element of the Riemannian manifold $\lbrace p \rbrace$. (See my comment below).

Best wishes

Comment: Usually, the Riemannian volume element is the one on the sphere, so you would get $0$ for your value, but your interpretation might be right, depending on the context.

Comment: The text discusses more generally the following situation: Let $N\subset S^2$ be a submanifold which arises as the fixed-point set of an isometry $\phi:S^2\rightarrow S^2$. Then it is $\int_{N}f(x)dvol_{N}(x)$ considered. If $N$ is a one dimensional submanifold (e.g. a great circle), it should be the Riemannian volume element of $N$ considered as a Riemannian submanifold of $S^2$ (Otherwise -since the submanifolds have measure zero w.r.t. the volume element on the sphere- the integrals would be zero for almost all $N$). But unfortunately I do not know what to do, if there is zero dimension...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know,

$\int_{ \lbrace P \rbrace } f(x)dvol_{ \lbrace P \rbrace }(x) = 0$

But for $\delta(x)$ to be the impulse function,

$\int_{ \lbrace P \rbrace } f(x)\delta(x)dvol_{ \lbrace P \rbrace }(x) = f(P)$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why do you think this is the right interpretation?

Comment: @HastiMusti It is because of the definition of integration and Direct Delta Function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

Comment: Do you know a reference, where I can find a definition which covers my situation, e.g. integration over zero dimensional Riemannian submanifolds or alike? (I have not asked about the dirac delta distribution, therefore I would suggest not to include it in our discussion)